# SQL Server : COUNT of a SUM with varying GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an Azure SQL database.

Say I have a table of order data with two columns `customer_id` and `items_purchased`:

```
| customer_id | items_purchased |
+-------------+-----------------+
| 1           | 1               |
| 2           | 2               |
| 3           | 1               |
| 1           | 4               |
| 2           | 3               |
| 4           | 3               |
| 5           | 2               |
| 6           | 2               |
| 6           | 1               |
```

I would like to know how many customers have bought a total of 1 item over their lifetime, how many have bought 2 items etc.

So for the above table, my desired result would be:

```
| total_items_purchased  | number_of_customers |
+------------------------+---------------------+
| 1                      | 1                   |
| 2                      | 1                   |
| 3                      | 2                   |
| 4                      | 0                   |
| 5                      | 2                   |
```

1 customer has a lifetime total of 1 item, 2 customers have a lifetime total of 3 items etc.

The closest I have got is an output of how many items each customer has bought using the below:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(items_purchased) 
FROM orderdata
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

But obviously this needs to be further grouped or something to get the result I need.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 2):

I think you want two levels of aggregation:

```
select num_items, count(*) as num_customers
from (select customer_id, sum(items_purchased) as num_items
      from t
      group by customer_id
     ) c
group by num_items
order by num_items;
```

Note:  This does not provide counts of `0`.

If you want counts of `0`, you need to generate the numbers.  One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with i as (
      select num_items, count(*) as num_customers
      from (select customer_id, sum(items_purchased) as num_items
            from t
            group by customer_id
           ) c
      group by num_items
     ),
     n as (
      select 1 as n, max(num_items) as maxn
      from i
      union all
      select n + 1, maxn
      from n
      where n < maxn
    )
select n.n, coalesce(i.num_customers, 0) as num_customers
from n left join
     i
     on n.n = i.num_items
with option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! I had actually written this exact query but without the 'c' after the content of the first FROM. What does that do? Why does it make it work?

Comment: @RFBM . . . SQL Server requires that subqueries in the `FROM` clause have a table alias.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.